# Update CHOSEN select box with jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using Unify template which has jquery `chosen` library for select boxes. My html code is as follows:

```
<div>
    <select class="select-evaluation-makes js-evaluation-custom-select u-select-v1 g-min-width-200 g-brd-none g-bg-secondary g-color-main g-color-primary--hover g-py-12"
            required
            data-placeholder="{% trans "Select brand" %}"
            data-open-icon="fa fa-angle-down"
            data-close-icon="fa fa-angle-up">
    </select>
    <select class="select-evaluation-models js-evaluation-custom-select u-select-v1 g-min-width-200 g-brd-none g-bg-secondary g-color-main g-color-primary--hover g-py-12"
            required disabled
            data-placeholder="{% trans "Seect model" %}"
            data-open-icon="fa fa-angle-down"
            data-close-icon="fa fa-angle-up">
    </select>
    <select class="select-evaluation-years js-evaluation-custom-select u-select-v1 g-min-width-200 g-brd-none g-bg-secondary g-color-main g-color-primary--hover g-py-12"
            required disabled
            data-placeholder="{% trans "Select year" %}"
            data-open-icon="fa fa-angle-down"
            data-close-icon="fa fa-angle-up">
    </select>
</div>
```

And my JS is as follows:

```
<script>
    const select_makes_selector = $(".select-evaluation-makes");
    const select_models_selector = $(".select-evaluation-models");
    const error_box = $("#error-box");
    const error_message = $("#error-message");

    $(document).ready(function () {

        loadMakesOnPageLoad();

        //Get models on make change
        select_makes_selector.on('change', function (e, params) {
            loadModels(parseInt(params["selected"]))
        });
    });

    function loadMakesOnPageLoad() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/vehicle-evaluation/get-makes/",
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (result) {
                let makes = result['makes'];
                select_makes_selector.append("<option></option>");
                _.forEach(makes, function (make) {
                    select_makes_selector.append("<option class=\"evaluation-make g-brd-none g-color-main g-color-white--hover g-color-white--active g-bg-primary--hover g-bg-primary--active\" value=\"" + make.id + "\">" + make.name + "</option>")
                });

                $.HSCore.components.HSSelect.init('.select-evaluation-makes');   
            },
            error: function (response) {
                error_box.removeClass("hidden");
                error_message.html('<strong>' + gettext("Oh snap!") + '</strong>' + gettext("Something went wrong. Makes couldn't be fetched"))
            }
        });
    }

    function loadModels(make_id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/vehicle-evaluation/get-models/" + make_id + '/',
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            success: function (result) {
                let models = result['models'];
                select_models_selector.attr('disabled', false).trigger("chosen:updated");
                select_models_selector.append("<option></option>");
                _.forEach(models, function (model) {
                    select_models_selector.append("<option class=\"evaluation-model g-brd-none g-color-main g-color-white--hover g-color-white--active g-bg-primary--hover g-bg-primary--active\" value=\"" + model.id + "\">" + model.name + "</option>")
                });
                $.HSCore.components.HSSelect.init('.select-evaluation-models');    
            },
            error: function (response) {
                error_box.removeClass("hidden");
                error_message.html('<strong>' + gettext("Oh snap!") + '</strong>' + gettext("Something went wrong. Models couldn't be fetched"))
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

The problem is with the initialisation of those select boxes. They can be initialised only once if I get it right.

With my code I get:

[image]

Thus only the first one is initialised with `$.HSCore.components.HSSelect.init('.select-evaluation-makes');` in `loadMakesOnPageLoad` function. But that is not what I want. All three need to be initialised.

If I change *brands select box*, then the *models select box* is also initialised. But If I change the *brands select box* again, then the *model select box* doesn't work and it isn't updated. It's probably because it hits `$.HSCore.components.HSSelect.init('.select-evaluation-models');` again in ajax success call of `loadModels` function.

If I initialise them with common class as follows: `$.HSCore.components.HSSelect.init('.js-evaluation-custom-select');` they are initialised:

[image]

But then `onChange` event on *brands select box* doesn't work. If the *brands select box* is changed then the *models select box* isn't updated, probably the same reason as above. It tries to initialise it again, this time with `$.HSCore.components.HSSelect.init('.select-evaluation-models');`

Any idea what is going on and how can I solve it? It drives me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

After you updated the `select` with ajax response put on the next line:

`$(".select-evaluation-makes").trigger("chosen:updated");`

> You must trigger "chosen:updated" event as per chosen [docs](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) show